# how to ignore mousePressEvent over GraphicsItem ( PyQt4)

Tags: python, pyqt

```
     import sys 

from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore
x=-40
y=0
z=0
class MyView(QtGui.QGraphicsView):


    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QGraphicsView.__init__(self)
        self.scene=QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.item=[]
        self.item2=[]
        myLine=QtGui.QGraphicsLineItem(-10,20,20,20)
        myLine.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.CrossCursor)
        self.scene.addItem(myLine)
        myLine.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)

        self.setScene(self.scene)

    def keyPressEvent(self,event):
        global x
        global y
        global z
        if event.key()==QtCore.Qt.Key_Left:

            self.item.append(QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem(x,-10,40,40))
            self.scene.addItem(self.item[y])
            x=x+10
            self.item[y].setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
            y=y+1
        elif event.key()==QtCore.Qt.Key_Right:

            self.item2.append(QtGui.QGraphicsEllipseItem(x,-10,40,40))
            self.scene.addItem(self.item2[z])
            x=x+10
            self.item2[z].setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
            z=z+1
    def mousePressEvent(self , event):
        self._start=event.pos()
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self,event):
         start = QtCore.QPointF(self.mapToScene(self._start))
             end = QtCore.QPointF(self.mapToScene(event.pos()))
             self.scene.addItem(
                    QtGui.QGraphicsLineItem(QtCore.QLineF(start, end)))

if __name__=='__main__':
    app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    view= MyView()
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

as you can see  i am not able to move the rectangles and ellipses because of the mouse press event it is drawing a line

i want to be able to drag as well as draw a line

when pressed over graphics item it should drag other wise it should draw line

Answer (score 1):

Use `if itemAt(event.pos) is None:` in `mousePressEvent()` to determine whether the click occurred over a `QGraphicsItem`. Set a state flag `self.__dragging = the_item` in that method, so that you can determine in the `mouseMoveEvent()` and the `mouseReleaseEvent()` whether you were dragging an object (`self.__dragging is not None`) or drawing a line (`self.__dragging is None`).